# Multiple SQL Quotes in one Field?

Tags: mysql

I can't solve this. I have a insert into select from SQL. Here:

```
INSERT INTO is_takip_new
( dosya_no
, isatama_tarihi
, muvekkil
, muvekkil_id
, son_tarih
, yapilacak_is
, alacak_karsitaraf
, alacak_tipi
, alacak_turu
, alacak_yaralanma_ID
, islem_turu
, alacak_plaka
, sorumlu_id
, tamamlandi
) 
SELECT alacak_yaralanma_dosyano
     , '$yapilmatarihi'
     , '$muvekkil'
     , '$muvekkil_id'
     , '$sontarih2'
     , alacak_yaralanma_karsitaraf 'şirketinin' alacak_yaralanma_plaka 'plakalı' alacak_yaralanma_turu 'dosyasında eksik evrak başvurusu yapılacak.'
     , alacak_yaralanma_karsitaraf
     , alacak_yaralanma_tipi
     , 'Yaralanma'
     , ID
     , 'Eksik Evrak Başvurusu'
     , alacak_yaralanma_plaka
     , '$sorumluID'
     , 0
  FROM alacak_yaralanma 
 WHERE alacak_yaralanma_dosyano = '$dosya_no' 
   AND alacak_yaralanma_muvekkil = '$muvekkil' 
   AND alacak_yaralanma_durum = 'Rapora Gönderildi'";
```

This part gives an error:

```
alacak_yaralanma_karsitaraf 'şirketinin' alacak_yaralanma_plaka 'plakalı' alacak_yaralanma_turu 'dosyasında eksik evrak başvurusu yapılacak.',
```

I want it to take the value first then write the 'blalbla' and take another value then write another 'blabla' until it ends. But couldn't solve the problem and still taking SQL error.

I will be so appreciated for any help. Thanks.

EDIT: Here is the error. Sorry: https://ibb.co/ZH5QV9c

Comment: Use parameters!  And never have this problem again.

Comment: Might want to include the exact error (number/message etc) that you're getting as well, now you're leaving it up to the readers to try and figure out what error you're getting.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Error added. Sorry again.

Comment: the SELECT part is invalid because you are referencing fields that aren't there or should be quoted.  This part `alacak_yaralanma_karsitaraf 'şirketinin' alacak_yaralanma_plaka 'plakalı' alacak_yaralanma_turu 'dosyasında eksik evrak başvurusu yapılacak.'` is particularly problematic. Are you wanting to join them together in a single value? If so look at the `CONCAT` mysql function. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat